# Spring-data-elasticsearch nested query not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

**Person.java**

```
@Document(indexName = "person", type = "user")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<Car> cars;

// getter/setter

}
```

**Car.java**

```
public class Car {

    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String model;

// getter/setter
}
```

Indexing and Searching using main method

```
public class SpringElasticSearchTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
                "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");

        ElasticsearchTemplate est = (ElasticsearchTemplate) applicationContext
                .getBean("elasticsearchTemplate");

        Person pers = new Person();
        pers.setName("Manish");
        pers.setId("1");

        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        Car subaru = new Car();
        subaru.setName("Tata");
        subaru.setModel("Safari");
        cars.add(subaru);
        pers.setCars(cars);

        IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQuery();
        indexQuery.setId(pers.getId());
        indexQuery.setObject(pers);

        est.deleteIndex("person");

        est.createIndex(Person.class);
        est.putMapping(Person.class);
        est.index(indexQuery);
        est.refresh(Person.class, true);

        QueryBuilder builder = nestedQuery(
                "cars",
                boolQuery().must(termQuery("cars.name", "Tata")).must(
                        termQuery("cars.model", "Safari")));
        SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(
                builder).build();
        List<Person> persons = est.queryForList(searchQuery, Person.class);
        System.out.println("Person List : " + persons);

    }
```

Indexing is working fine but searching functionally is not working.
I am getting the following output:

> Person List : []

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I find the solution, The query I have built while searching

```
termQuery("cars.name", "Tata")
```

should be in lower case so the correct query would be -

```
QueryBuilder builder = nestedQuery(
                "cars",
                boolQuery().must(termQuery("cars.name", "tata")).must(
                        termQuery("cars.model", "safari")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would have been to use a matchQuery, which is case-insensitive by default:

```
QueryBuilders.matchQuery("cars.name", "Tata")
```

Or you can use an analyzer that does not lower case, unlike the standard one.

related discussion here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-do-case-insensitive-search-on-terms/19790